# PHP7 under OS X Server creates Cache/Memory issues

Tags: php, macos, server

i have a OS X Server (Yosemity) with activated Filsharing, App-Cache and Webserver. After upgrading to PHP7 an PHP-Webapplication that worked fine under PHP5.6 now creates memory issues (as I think): It gets slowler and slower. Only a restart of the Webservice (in the Server Control App) helps and for the next 30 Minutes or so the PHP-Application works again. I tried to enable/disable caches, used even the purge command to clear memopry of OS X, but nothing works... I am a bit helpless and would appreciate any ideas where else to look.

regards
olaf